# Combine multiple Flow<List<T>> to a Single Flow<Map<String, List<T>>>

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to convert multiple Flow results from different @Query on Room database to a Flow of Map of those result List. Something like this:

```
 fun getA(): Flow<List<T>> // query 1

 fun getB(): Flow<List<T>>// query 2
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
fun getMappedList(): Flow<Map<String, List<T>>> {

    val mapList = mutableMapOf<String, List<T>>()
    
    return flow {
        getA().map{
          mapList["A"] = it
       }
        getB().map{
          mapList["B"] = it
        }

         emit(mapList)
      }
    
    }
```

But clearly that seems not to be working. Any ideas how i can achieve this. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't really used the `Flow` api much, but something like this should work :

```
fun getMappedList(): Flow<Map<String, List<Int>>> 
        = getA().combine(getB()) { a, b  ->  mapOf(Pair("A", a), Pair("B", b))  }
```

Or depending on your usecase you might want to use the `zip` operator, to emit as unique "pairs" :

```
fun getMappedList(): Flow<Map<String, List<Int>>> 
        = getA().zip(getB()) { a, b  ->  mapOf(Pair("A", a), Pair("B", b))  }
```

Tested using :

```
fun getA(): Flow<List<Int>> = flow { emit(listOf(1)) }

fun getB(): Flow<List<Int>> = flow { emit(listOf(2)); emit(listOf(3)) }

fun getCombine(): Flow<Map<String, List<Int>>> 
           = getA().combine(getB()) { a, b  ->  mapOf(Pair("A", a), Pair("B", b))  }

fun getZip(): Flow<Map<String, List<Int>>> 
           = getA().zip(getB()) { a, b  ->  mapOf(Pair("A", a), Pair("B", b))  }
```

output in the collector for `combine` (combines latest values from either flow) :

`{A=[1], B=[2]}`

`{A=[1], B=[3]}`

output in the collector for `zip` (zip pairs of emissions from each flow) :

`{A=[1], B=[2]}`

**Update**

Having used the api a bit more you can use `combine` which can take `n` number of `Flow<T>` :

```
val flowA =  flow<Int> { emit(1) }
val flowB =  flow<Int> { emit(2) }
val flowC =  flow<Int> { emit(3) }
    
combine(flowA, flowB, flowC, ::Triple)
```

Comment: What would you do if you needed to combine three flows?

Comment: something like : `combine(flowA, flowB, flowC, ::Triple)` or `combine(flowA, flowB, flowC) { a, b, c -> combine here}`